# How do I properly make the dark mode settings menu work?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin, android-darkmode

So I completed the first lesson of the Kotlin Course by Google on Udacity and after that I went on to make my own changes to the app that make them look better (just to learn, I don't care about the app). I made some changes like adding dark mode and customizing the UI.

I want the dark mode menu to work properly, like when I click on `light mode` it should recreate the activity with light mode enabled and should also check the light mode `MenutItem`. I also want the app to remember the settings so that if I choose `Follow System` during one session of the app and then close the app, it should keep following the system even after opening the app. I figured this should be done with `SharedPreferences` but I don't know how to properly do it. As you can see in the video attached below, when I click on any of the dark mode settings options, they don't automatically change the settings, I need to restart the app and only then do I see any changes in the activity that matches to whatever option I selected before closing the app.

**Note: I want to mention that I am not very experienced with Android Development or Kotlin, I only started learning 2 months ago. I also want to mention that I DO NOT care about the app itself but I am rather using this app to learn how to get things done. I don't care if my app gets every feature I
would want it to have if I don't also learn how to do those things. It's not the app but the knowledge that I am getting from it that I care about, this is to say that please if you have an answer, do explain how that works.**

This video shows the behavior of the app: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SnN0r351OGF4xQNCtI1wtgouSFVROKzg/view?usp=sharing

I added a `toolbar` to my layout file of the main (and the only) activity. Here's the xml code for the layout resource:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/diceRollerActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/activity_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:title="@string/app_name" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dice_image"
        android:layout_width="275dp"
        android:layout_height="335dp"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/diceImage_imageView_description"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.395"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/empty_dice" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/roll_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/Container_Button_Padding"
        android:text="@string/roll"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/bold_button_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dice_image"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32"
        app:rippleColor="@color/button_ripple" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is my the Kotlin code for the same activity:

```
package com.example.diceroller

import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.*
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var diceImage: ImageView
    lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.activity_toolbar))
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.roll_button)
        diceImage = findViewById(R.id.dice_image)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollDice()
        }

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        when (sharedPreferences.getString("Night_Mode_State", getString(R.string.follow_system))) {
            getString(R.string.follow_system) -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
            getString(R.string.light_mode) -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
            getString(R.string.dark_mode) -> AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        val inflater: MenuInflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.follow_system -> sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Night_Mode_State", getString(R.string.follow_system)).apply()
            R.id.light_mode -> sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Night_Mode_State", getString(R.string.light_mode)).apply()
            R.id.dark_mode -> sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Night_Mode_State", getString(R.string.dark_mode)).apply()
        }
        return true
    }
    private fun rollDice() {
        when ((1..6).random()) {
            1 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)
            2 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_2)
            3 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_3)
            4 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_4)
            5 -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_5)
            else -> diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_6)
        }
    }
}
```

This gist includes other files that I think are required to answer this question properly, namely: The menu resource file, the colors resource file and the styles resource file: [https://gist.github.com/sbeve72/36a71919f1f965c5dcd466db1e099b4f.js"](https://gist.github.com/sbeve72/36a71919f1f965c5dcd466db1e099b4f.js%22)

Comment: Your usage of `SharedPreferences` seems to be just fine. If you don't want to save changes at every change, you could apply changes in a callback such as `onPause`. As for the radio buttons, they probably have some sort of `setSelection` method which you can use to mark the correct selection when appropriate (e.g. when you determine the theme). And to immediately change the values I think it should suffice if you make the appropriate call to `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` in the `when` cases in `onOptionsItemSelected`, just as you do in `onCreate`.

Comment: apart from what you said about sharedpreferences and `onPause` I have tried the other two things but I just couldn't do it he right way to get things working as intended. Idk why like I want it to change the app's dark mode setting to whatever the user chose in options menu the last time he opened the app and selected an option. Also I want, for example, light mode from the options menu to be selected if the last time the user chose the Light Mode `MenuItem` and like I said above, i also want the app to load with light mode enabled

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will have to make the calls to `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode` in `onOptionsItemSelected`. Perhaps changing your style to `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">` will help. Maybe this blog post can be useful to you: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94. As far as the button selections are concerned, `RadioButton.setChecked()` should do it (at the beginning, when you determine the current theme, check the corresponding radio button).

Comment: how do I get a reference to MenuItems to give to RadioButton.setChecked()?

Comment: My guess is you have a layout/menu file where you have added your buttons. Give them an id (e.g. `android:id="@+id/my_radio_button"`), then you can get them in your code (e.g. `myRadioButton = findViewById(R.id.my_radio_button)`). Once you have it, you can make the call (`myRadioButton.setChecked(isChecked)`). Note that instead/in addition you may want to work with the `RadioGroup`, which you can retrieve in a similar manner. But I'd say try to get it done like this first.

Comment: `MenuItems` aren't view objects, `findViewById` doesn't work for them. It needs to be a view. 
Also is there a method that lets me recreate the activity whenever needed? Instead of using `setDefaultNightMode` inside a `when` statement in `onOptionsMenuSelected()`, I would just write to `SharedPreferences` and restart the activity and let the `when` statement inside my activity class set the theme.

Comment: Yes, there is: `recreate()`, see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#recreate(). I see it now in your `menu.xml`. They should have a similar method. In general, if you have an XML field such as `android:checked` you will have something similar for that element on the code side. It may not always be trivial though.

Comment: I have read dozens of search results and couldn't find a method to find reference to `MenuItems` by id

Comment: I am currently at work and I'll be busy tonight. I'll see if I can do something about it tomorrow if you're still stuck by then. Ideally you send me your code, otherwise I'll set something up myself.

Comment: What code? I already have everything attached to the post. I appreciate your help. I am still stuck. I will make posts on some subreddits.

Comment: What I meant is a zip of your project or a link to some repo, because what you've provided is incomplete (e.g. missing image files, `string.xml`, etc.). But I've found your repo and it seems you've got it done. Good job. I don't think that you have to `recreate()` your activity though. For me it works if I just call (e.g.) `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)` instead.